# Root-level routing with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

How do I efficiently enable root-level routing with Ruby on Rails?

For example, instead of having:

```
/questions/a-question-here
```

I want:

```
/a-question-here
```

What technology would I use, and how would I configure the routing to enable this?

EDIT: I also have other models such as videos and users, so I'd like the routing to match other controllers as well. For example, how do I get /username to go to some action in the Users controller and /some-video-title to go to some action in the Videos controller?

Thanks for all your help, people.

Comment: What's the Redis for? That's just a database store.

Comment: ctcherry's answer is correct but I'd reiterate his warning.  Is what you're asking for good design for your site?  Having user generated data "pollute" your "root level" is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I was thinking maybe Redis would be used to map URLs to their controller and action, perhaps? 
As far as the design goes, the root-level directory structure is purely for SEO purposes. I've never done this before so I have no idea whether it's a good idea. All I know is that Quora does it and Quora has really good SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails has a very configurable routing layer built in. Good documentation here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Your route could end up looking something like this:

```
match ":id" => "questions#show"
```

Depending on where you put that, it could override a lot of other routes, so be aware of that.

Comment: One caveat here is that the `:id` parameter should contain only letters, numbers, dashes and underscores. Other characters may cause it to behave strangely, or not work at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if there are more controller actions - how do I get :id, etc., to match them? (See modified question.) Thanks.

Comment: Thats a very different situation, now you will have to look at that same section of the URL, and determine what it is. That string, presumably, won't have any qualities that would allow you to differentiate a video title from a question title. It's not really a good practice to mix different resources into the same "path namespace" as you are wanting to do.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I'll take your advice. Thanks for all your help!